# Run configuration setup in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, run-configuration

I can run my Spring Boot jar in Git Bash with the following command:

```sh
java -Dspring.profiles.active=development -Djasypt.encryptor.password=$JASYPT_DEV_PWD -DAPP_LOGS=C:/temp/logs -DDEBUG_OPTS -jar target/application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I'm now trying to run the application in IntelliJ. The run configuration contains the following:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=development
-Djasypt.encryptor.password=$JASYPT_DEV_PWD
-DAPP_LOGS=C:\\temp\\logs
```

When I run the application in my IDE I get:

> IllegalStateException: Required Encryption configuration property missing: jasypt.encryptor.password

I tried setting the value for `JASYPT_DEV_PWD` in my system environment variables, my run configuration environment variables and also passing the password directly in the `-Djasypt.encryptor.password=`.

How should I set my run configuration to get the application working in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1):

Moved `-Djasypt.encryptor.password=$JASYPT_DEV_PWD` to environmental variables in the run configuration. Didn't seem to work with `$JASYPT_DEV_PWD` though so copied the actual password in.

Comment: You can create JASYPT_DEV_PWD variable under `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Path Variables` and then use `$JASYPT_DEV_PWD$` in the Run/Debug configuration environment variables.

Comment: I don't have the actual password, any other workaround ?

Comment: I think you'd need it.